# cannot disable cypress screenshots

Tags: cypress

I am trying to disable cypress screenshots, I have this in my `cypress.json`:

```
{
  "pluginsFile": "cypress/plugins/index.js",
  "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.ts",
  "video": false,
  "screenshotOnRunFailure": false
}
```

But the screenshots are still happening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must set this option with [`Cypress.Screenshot.defaults()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/screenshot-api.html).

In your `cypress/support/index.js` file add

```
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
  screenshotOnRunFailure: false
})
```

Comment: There is any way to do this using CLI arguments or env variables? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To disable through the command line the creation of video and screenshots, you can do the following:

```
cypress run --config video=false,screenshotOnRunFailure=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the route of adding things to `cypress/support/index.js` a solution to this could be to have multiple `cypress.json` config files.
For example:
one config file that allows screenshots (ie. `"screenshotOnRunFailure": true`) called `allowScreenshotsConfig.json`, and one that doesn't (ie. `"screenshotOnRunFailure": false`), called `disallowScreenshotsConfig.json`

Then all you will need to is [target a specific config file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-open-config-file-lt-config-file-gt) when you run Cypress, using something like `cypress open --config-file tests/allowScreenshotsConfig.json`